# Javascript, change a link color when mouse is over it, only after I click a button

Tags: javascript, html

I have an assignment to do (so there is rules regarding css use and jquery etc).

*edit: I need to do it entirely through javascript, I can't use css or jquery, sorry for not being more specific (although i'm sure the css and jquery answers will be useful to others!*

Basically when I click a button I want my javascript to become active.

one of the features I want is that when my mouse is over a link it changes colour, and when it is no longer on the link it it goes back to the prior colour. I know how I would generally do this with `"onmouseover""onmouseout"`. but I don't know how to do this so it only happens after I click a button

```
function linkA()
{
    setInterval(changeImage, 3000);
    changeLink();
}
```

this is some of the code that activates when the button is pressed it then activates the function change link

```
function changeLink()
{
    var x = document.getElementById('sidebar').getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(var i = 0; i<x.length; i++)
    {
         x[i].style.color = "blue";
    }
}
```

this is to change the link colours to blue, then i was thinking of using something like

```
`x.onmouseover = x.style.color="green";
 x.onmouseout = x.style.color='blue';`
```

to change the colour when i have the mouse over it, but I'm not even sure if that is valid code or if could work, any help is much appreciated!

This is the piece of html i wish to edit, there is more than three links on the rest of the page outside the div tag i just want to alter these three however

```
<div id="sidebar">
                <div>
                    <h3>Recent Articles</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="article.html">Why the bird is a natural replacement for the bee</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="article.html">stone work in your garden, the new trend</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="article.html">Urban family turns garden into eco farm</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="article.html">sheep as your lawn mower! revolutionary eco gardening</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: You could use the button to give the links a new class. And then have a new CSS rule for hovering over links with that class.

Comment: @Jay that's the way to go, write that as an answer with an example, I'll vote for it.

Comment: @StephenP Thankyou, and I have done. May be late to the party though, think there are some other valid answers already!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the link only to change colors AFTER you press a button. To do this, you could use a boolean. Something like

```
var clicked = false;
var onButtonClick = function() { clicked = !clicked; }
x.onmouseover = function () {
    x.style.color = clicked ? 'green' : 'blue'
}
x.onmouseout = function () {
    x.style.color = 'blue'
}
```

Comment: I get the concept but i'm not quite sure how to work it in my code (its a littl bit over my head). I was thinking of using a boolean and declaring it false outside my function and once i enter my function "linkA" declaring it true then using an if statement and using the onmouse over, would that work?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long. That's essentially what's happening in my code. The variable 'clicked' is outside any function and set to false. The variable 'onButtonClick' is a function that is your 'linkA' function. The clicked equals not clicked part sets clicked to true if it's false, and false if it's true. Lastly, the onmouseover function sets x.style.color to green if 'clicked' is true, and blue otherwise. The question mark/colon syntax is shorthand for an if statement.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the full problem.. You could use the button to give a new class to either, the specific / all anchors on the page *OR* a parent element of some kind. Then use a specific CSS selector to change the color of the links with that class.

**[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/1jfxyccp/)**

**HTML:**

```
<button id="someButton">Text</button>

<div id="someDiv">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a> 
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
a:hover {
    color: green;
}

#someDiv.newClass a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( '#someButton' ).click( function() {

        if( $( '#someDiv' ).hasClass( 'newClass' ) ) {

            $( '#someDiv' ).removeClass( 'newClass' );
        }
        else {

            $( '#someDiv' ).addClass( 'newClass' );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry for not being specific, I need to do it entirely through javascript! thanks for the answer tho and hopefully it will help someone else

Comment: Use `toggleClass` instead of `hasClass => removeClass else addClass`. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/1jfxyccp/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Try `x.onmouseup()` . It strictly checks to see if the mouse button is lifted over an object.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost correct. You need to use:

```
x.onmousedown = function () {
  x.style.color="green";
}
x.onmouseup = function () {
  x.style.color='blue';
}
```

Test it here:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("x");

x.onmousedown = function () {
  x.style.color="green";
}
x.onmouseup = function () {
  x.style.color='blue';
}
```

```html
<strong id="x">Click on me to change colour!</strong>
```

Comment: I think that helped me a bit, is it possible to swap "x.onmousedown" for "x.onmouseover", can I use that code in my existing function or does it have to be outside my function. i wasn't specific enough either in my initial question (apologies) but I only want to change three links n the entire webpage and the three links are contained within a div tag, (there is more than three links on the page. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 1):

"Basically when I click a button I want my javascript to become active."

You can use an event listener to attach other event listeners.

HTML:

```
<h3>Recent Articles</h3>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="article1.html">Article 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="article2.html">Article 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="article3.html">Article 3</a></li>
  </ul>

<button id="activate">Click here to attach some event listeners.</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); 

var activator = document.getElementById('activate');

// Apply the hover effects...
function attachColorChangers(x) {
  x.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    x.style.color = 'green';
  });
  x.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    x.style.color = 'blue';
  });
} 

// ... after the button is clicked.
activator.addEventListener('click', function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i += 1) {
    attachColorChangers(links[i]);
  }
});
```